# Photopicker руками

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Недавно начал изучать программирование под ios. пока тренируюсь в xcode 4.2 . Хочу написать фотопикер(примерно как оригинальное приложение для просмотра фотографий). в ios 6  и далее для этого есть Collection View . для ios 5 такового нет. и  вообще хотелось бы самому понять ,как можно его написать. пока делаю все программно ,без IB. я так понял он делается в tableview. Может у кого -нибудь есть идеи как это сделать или кто-нибудь знает , где разбирали подобную задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cocoacontrols Ваше все](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=photo) - лучший мануал для ios.